# My wordpress website google map not working

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, plugins

I have a wordpress website. On contact us page my google map not work properly. It display a msg like this page cant load properly or for development purpose only. My google map plugin Version 4.1.1 display a warning that This plugin has not been tested with your current version of WordPress.How can I resolve this issue kindly help out me

Comment: you can ask your plugin  developer to update or you can look for another plugin compatible with your current version of wordpress.

Comment: Usually this error is caused by either not using an API key, or using an API key without a billing account enabled on the project. Can you check the map related error in your page when you open the 'Developer Tools' window by clicking CTRL + SHIFT + I or press F12  (on a Mac, use CMD + Option + I)?

Answer (score -1):

The fix is really simple: just replace YOUR_API_KEY on the last line of your code with your actual API key!

If you don't have one, you can get it for free on the Google Developers Website.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: i have already added my api key in te setting but i dont know why this is happning kindly elaorate in steps

Answer (score -1):

Maybe plugin is just not marked for compatibility with new WordPress version but works. Most probably API key issue. If there is no input on plugin side. Just add initialization for Google Maps in your child theme header.php.